# ClassNotFoundException in eclipse while making a webservice call

Tags: java, xml, apache

I am facing an issue respective to making a web service

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My web.xml is

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> <servlet>   <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> <servlet-class>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer </servlet-class> <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.helloRS</param-value>   </init-param>   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet> <servlet-mapping>   <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> </web-app>
```

Comment: Provide the code ,, so that it can be fixed

Comment: package com.helloRS;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 @Path("/hello")
 public class HelloResource {
     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String sayHello() {
         return "Hello Jersey";
     }
 }

Comment: a simple hello jersey program

Comment: @sailaja.p: you can copy the code in your question itself, you can edit and add your code

Comment: still code is required ,
You may might have not imported library/ jars

Comment: Have you added (and deployed) proper dependencies to your project?

Comment: I have added lib/jars